# The effect of otherwise inconsequential calls to readlines() on the speed of open(filepath) in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a university assignment that consists in building a hash table.

One of the tasks requires that we measure the time taken to associate a list of keys with some value, and measure the effects of different hash bases and different table capacities on the execution time. Incidentally, collisions are resolved by linear probing.

We're asked to read the keys from a file and associate them with the value of 1, as in:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        line = line.strip('\n')
        hashtable[line] = 1
```

However, given certain combinations of suboptimal hash bases and table capacities, such as 1 and 250,727 respectively, or 3 and 250,727, the excerpt above is intolerably slow. It seems to run indefinitely. For instance, it didn't complete after running for several hours!

Curiously, if I add some expression like `len(data.readlines())` or `type(data.readlines())`, accessing the `file` object before entering the loop, then the program completes in less than one second with the same parameters.

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as data:
    len(data.readlines())
    for line in data.readlines():
        line = line.strip('\n')
        hashtable[line] = 1
```

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Because when you use `readlines()` it exhausted the iterator and the next time you'll get empty output

Comment: Of course! How silly of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The length is calculated where based on where `the file starts(The memory location at which the file starts) - where the file ends(The memory location at which the file ends)`.
It is an **O(1)** operation that why it takes less time.
On the other hand, insertion in a hashtable is an **O(1)** operation but depending on the *number of entries the total time taken would be* **O(n)**. **O(1)** for each number so total **O(n)** for *n entries*. But if you are implementing a linear probing method for collision handling.
Maybe an element sarts at 1st position and gets hashed at the end of the hashtable. So, here the **worst-case complexity would be O(n^2)**. If you could upload the file on cloud and share the link i would be able to share some more analytics.